# trying to get the name of the month in awk using system

Tags: shell, scripting, awk

I am trying to get the name of the month in awk using the following code.

```
 system("date -d" dat "+%b")
```

How do I assign the output to a variable?

Comment: Which version of awk on which platforms?  It will matter, because GNU awk has functionality that is not available elsewhere.

Comment: Also, at some point, read [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).  You'd realize that you are asking the wrong question.  You should be asking: '_How can I get the month name from a Unix timestamp in `awk`?_', possibly with a comment 'I was wondering if there was a way to get the output from a command run by `system`, so I could use the `date` command to do the conversion?'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/awk-assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable see this thread

Comment: The [x-ref'd question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/awk-assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable) is good for the question actually asked ('_How do I assign the output of `system` to a variable?_') as long as you're using GNU `awk`.  However, if you're using GNU `awk`, there's a better way to handle the real question '_How do I get the month name from a Unix timestamp in `awk`?_', using the built-in GNU time manipulation functions.

Comment: bash-3.2$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2005 Free Software Foundation.

bash-3.2$ uname -a
Linux server 2.6.18-194.11.4.el5 #1 SMP Fri Sep 17 04:57:05 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I am trying to get the month name using predetermined string, not according to the system month.

Comment: Note that the "-d" option for date is OS-specific, and not portable.  In case that matters to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "How do I populate a variable with the output of a command line", then the answer is "pipes".  :-)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ str="date \"+%b\""; str | getline content; print content; }'
Dec
```

Note that this is probably not what you *really* want to be doing, but without more detail about your intentions, at least it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use `system()`? What about awk's `strftime()`? You can look at an example [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_180.html) (though it seems to be GNU-awk specific).

Comment: I am trying to check whether the function is working according to the given string. dat="20111016"; MONTH=strftime("%b",substr(dat,5,2));
When I change the string, it is still giving me MONTH as DEC.

Comment: So the string '20111016' represents 2011-10-16 (16th October 2011), rather than a Unix timestamp?  Then you probably need to look harder at the GNU `awk` time functions - and `mktime` in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v dat="20111016" 'BEGIN{split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec",month,","); a=substr(dat,5,2); print month[a]}'
Oct
```