# How to get system output in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to store the printf output to the array like below:

```
op[i] = system( "printf \"%d\\n\" \"" SQ substr($1,i,1) "\"" )
```

but when I call them back , they just 0 ?!

Do you know why!?

Comment: `system()` returns 0, hence that's what you'll get. You'll have to use a stream to get the actual output as a string. Also, is printf a system command? If you're trying to use the C++ function of printf, you're not supposed to use `system()`.

Comment: awk has it's own printf function OR you can use 'string' printf, i.e. `ar[0]=sprintf(.....)`

Comment: @Griffin: There is a [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) command that is a bit like `echo` in that it echoes data to its standard output, but under the control of a format string like `printf()` (the function).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning system command's output to variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want

```
op[i] = sprintf("%d\n", SQ substr($1,i,1))
```

The way to capture output from an external command:

```
cmd = "date"
cmd | getline output
close(cmd)
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe