# How to extract the system command output into a variable inside an awk program?

Tags: file, awk, io-redirection

The output of the system command that I invoke from my AWK script is being displayed on the terminal. I do not want the shell to display the output of the system command but rather want this output to be read into a variable of the script (the output of the system command is a one-word string either "yes" or "no"). This variable then needs to be compared with a string in the script (if its "yes" or "no") and the output from the command finally needs to be saved into a new file. How do I do this in AWK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWK: Assigning system command's output to variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/awk-assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable)

Comment: I went through the solution listed in the other post. The getline solution listed there does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
"command" | getline var
```

That will execute `command` and put the output, one line at a time, into the variable `var`. e.g.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{while("seq 3" | getline x) print "output: " x}'
output: 1
output: 2
output: 3
```

And it will persist between calls too:

```
$ seq 3 | awk '{"seq 4 7" | getline x; print x}'
4
5
6
```

Note the 7 is not printed because there isn't a fourth line of input.

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960895/900873) shows using `|&`, which doesn't appear in the man page, and I'm not sure what the difference is. I thought it might capture stderr too, but it's not doing that in my tests.

Comment: I'm not running an awk command on the shell but rather a program script with other awk commands. When I tried using the solution using getline, it threw an error saying Bad Interpreter. I guess getline is not supported in my implementation of awk. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: 'bad interpreter' usually means an incorrect shebang, not an incorrect command. Post the precise error you're getting.