# wget gives error while calling it inside AWK using two-way I/O

Tags: awk, pipe, wget

I need to get the output of a `wget` call inside an `aw`k script. However, for some reason the `wget` call fails when I'm using the [two-way I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/awk-assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable).

My attempts are (in a MWE form):

Using a loop to capture several lines:

```
echo http://www.del-rio.net/images/festival/medium/2000_0516_Ellen_Burstyn_1274-1-4.jpg | awk '{
  cmd = "wget -t 1 $0";
  while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ){
    result = result " " line;
  }     
  print result;
  close (cmd);
 }'
```

And using a single line. This one I tried with and without the non-verbose option, as the wget call with `-nv` option returns one line only.

```
 echo http://www.del-rio.net/images/festival/medium/2000_0516_Ellen_Burstyn_1274-1-4.jpg | gawk '{
  "wget -t 1 -nv $0" | getline line;   
  print line;
}'
```

However, in both cases it stops and gives the message:

```
--22:09:09--  http://sh/
          => `index.html' 
Resolving sh... failed: Host not found.
```

Am I doing something wrong? or `wget` does not work in this pipe mode? In that case, how can I obtain the result of the call in a variable inside the `awk` script.

Comment: try echo 'http://....' | gawk ... Good luck.

Comment: @shelter it didn't work, same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `wget` output is redirected to the stderr instead of the standard output. Thus, the `getline` will never capture it (as far as I know).

So my solution was to redirect the log outputs to the standard output and then handling the line.

Also as noted by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515877/424986), the problem with the host not resolving was the `$0` variable inside of the quotes.

Thus, putting all together it works like this

```
echo http://www.absolutely.net/wenn/handy_manny_05_wenn5360250.jpg  | awk '{
  cmd = "wget -t 1 " $0 " 2>&1"
  while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ){
    result = result " " line
  }
  close(cmd)
  print "the result: " result
}'
```

Comment: don't forget the `close(cmd)`. I do wonder why you're doing it this way at all rather than invoking wget outside of awk but I'm guessing this must be a small part of a much larger script.

Answer (score 1):

Move $0 outside of the quotes, i.e. do this:

```
"wget... " $0
```

instead of this:

```
"wget... $0"
```

Unrelated but: get rid of all those null statements (trailing semi-colons) that are cluttering up your script.

Comment: Now that I move the `$0` outside of the quotes the `wget` runs, but still I get no output in the `result` variable, it's empty