# Redirection output to a file

Tags: shell, awk

cat sun.csv is as follows
"list of files| here it is|ls -l"
i am able to get the output
but not able to redirect it to the file (i.e.asd.csv)
how to re direct the complete output?
this is the code
a.sh(file name)

```
#/usr/bin/ksh
awk ' BEGIN{FS="|"} {printf "\033[4m%s:\n\033[0m", $1;print $2;system($3);} ' sun.csv >> asd.csv

$./a.sh
```

cat asd.csv has correct output till `printf "\033[4m%s:\n\033[0m", $1;print $2;` and nothing after that

Comment: can't be reproduced here..

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: does `more -v asd.csv` work ?  -v preserves colors/etc set by the \033[Xm ansi codes

Comment: the problem probably lies in the `system($3)` call. first replace it with :  `print "system (" $3 ");" `  to just have a display of what invocation of system would take place, and check it for potential errors

Comment: @Olivier Dulac is right i too suspect the same place but dont knwo what to do.Coz system() will return just o or 1 if i am correct so dont know how to change it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/awk-assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to do this:

```
$3 | getline var; print var; close($3)
```

instead of

```
system($3)
```

but I wouldn't recommend doing either one. If you tell us what you're trying to do we could probably help.