# Use sed or awk to fix date format

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to convert a HTML containing a table to a .csv file using a `bash` script.

So far I've acomplished the following steps:

1. Convert to Unix format (with `dos2unix`)
2. Remove all spaces and tabs (with `sed 's/[ \t]//g'`)
3. Remove all the blank lines (with `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'`) (this is necesary, because the HTML file has a blank line for each cell of the table... that's not my fault)
4. Remove the unnecesary `<td>`  and `<tr>` tags (with `sed 's/<t.>//g'`)
5. Replace `</td>` with ',' (with `sed 's/<\/td/,/g'`)
6. Replace `</tr>` with end-of-line (`\n`) characters (with `sed 's/<\/tr/\n/g'`)

Of course, I'm putting all this in a pipeline. So far, it's working great. There's one final step I'm stuck with: The table has a column with dates, which has the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, and I'd like to convert them to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Is there a (simple) way to do it (with `sed` or `awk`)?

**Data sample** (after the whole `sed` pipe):

```
500,2,13/09/2007,30000.00,12,B-1
501,2,15/09/2007,14000.00,8,B-2
```

**Expected result**:

```
500,2,2007-09-13,30000.00,12,B-1
501,2,2007-09-15,14000.00,8,B-2
```

The reason I need to do this is because I need to import this data to MySQL. I could open the file in Excel and change the format by hand, but I would like to skip that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Awk` can do this task pretty easily:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } 
    { split($3, date, /\//)
      $3 = date[3] "-" date[2] "-" date[1]
      print $0 
    }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
500,2,2007-09-13,30000.00,12,B-1
501,2,2007-09-15,14000.00,8,B-2
```

Answer (score 12):

```
sed -E 's,([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}),\3-\2-\1,g'
```

Comment: Pasted this in as a first-pass example to get things going and it worked verbatim! Thanks @ash!

Answer (score 6):

```
sed "s:,\([0-9]\+\)/\([0-9]\+\)/\([0-9]\+\),:,\3-\2-\1,:"
```

Answer (score 5):

`awk` would work for this:

```
echo 08/26/2013 | awk -F/ '{printf "%s-%s-%s\n",$3,$2,$1}'
```

as would one of these `bash`-only options:

```
IFS=/ read m d y < <(echo 08/26/2013); echo "${y}-${m}-${d}"
IFS=/ read m d y <<< "08/26/2013"; echo "${y}-${m}-${d}"
```

If you happen to use `ksh`, where a subshell is not used for the last component of a pipeline, this should work as well:

```
echo 08/26/2013 | IFS=/ read m d y; echo "${y}-${m}-${d}"
```

In recent `bash`, you can also use `shopt -s lastpipe` in a script to allow the above invocation to work as well, but it won't work on the command line (thanks to @mklement0 in the comments below).

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to integrate it with the rest...

Comment: Nice, but the `read`-based command won't work, because `read` runs in a _subshell_ in this case; use `echo '08/26/2013' | { IFS=/ read m d y; echo "${y}-${m}-${d}"; }` or
`IFS=/ read m d y <<<'08/26/2013'; echo "${y}-${m}-${d}"`

Comment: @mklement0 Ah, yes.... forgot about that little detail. It would work in `ksh`, though. Another alternative would be `IFS=/ read m d y < <(echo 08/26/2013)` to avoid the subshell (although the `echo` would be in a subshell).

Comment: Good points, though `<<<` is probably most efficient here. In Bash v4.2+ you can also use `shopt -s lastpipe` (but only in scripts). Can I suggest tht you update your answer with one of the working solutions?

Answer (score 4):

So far all answers are very case specific to OP's issue.  Here is a more general approach, running (GNU, for `-d` option) `date` through `awk` :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
     {
       "date -d\"" $3 "\" +%Y-%m-%d" | getline mydate; 
       print $1 "," $2 "," mydate "," $4 "," $5 "," $6
     }'
```

Of course this approach will work as is only if the input date format is handled by `date`.  AFAICS this is not the case for `dd/mm/yyyy`, unfortunately.  One may try [other commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56854/26952) than `date` (not tested).

Edit : Implemented mklement0's comment.

Edit2 : Actually this doesn't work with `mawk`, which is Debian's default `awk` implementation.  Obvious solution is to install `gawk` when possible.

Comment: ++, but you should mention that _GNU_ `date` is required due to `-d`; similarly, `|&` is a GNU Awk extension, but not actually needed here: `|` will do, which makes it work with all Awks.
Finally, I suggest you use spaces between the strings being concatenated, both for visual clarity and to show that string concatenation in Awk works differently
than in the shell; e.g., `"date -d'" $3 "' +%Y-%m-%d"` (I've also added single quotes to guard against the field having embedded spaces).

Comment: @mklement0 : Thanks for your suggestions, I've edited the answer.  Single quotes won't do, I replaced them with escaped double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, and thanks for catching my single-quotes mistake (just to state it explicitly: single quotes cannot be used inside the Awk script, because the script as a whole is single-quoted).

Comment: This yields incorrect results when there are many input lines; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630820/10376320) for the correct approach using `close()`

Answer (score 2):

correction to awk assume you seek yyyy-mm-dd (not yyyy-dd-mm)

> echo 08/26/2013 | awk -F/ '{printf "%s-%s-%s\n",$3,$1,$2}'