# Import CSV with escaped newline/tab characters

Tags: mysql, r, csv

I'm trying to import into R a CSV file produced by MySQL's `SELECT … INTO OUTFILE` with default settings. The database produces a nice tab-separated file which apparently escapes tab characters and newlines in a way I've never seen: the literal newline (ASCII code 10) or tab character (ASCII code 9) is preceded with a backslash.

Example of a file with three fields (I use `→` to represent a tab character here):

A normal line without any escapes:

```
field1→field2→field3
```

The first field contains an escaped tab character:

```
long\→field1→field2→field3
```

The first field contains a new line character:

```
long\
field1→field2→field3
```

I tried to use:

```
scan('file.csv', what=list('character', 'character', 'character'), sep='\t', quote='', na.strings='\\N', allowEscapes=TRUE)
```

…but the `allowEscapes` parameter doesn't catch this case. Is there any way to import such file?

Comment: I would clean it using `sed` (or `awk`) before trying to import it to R. I had some issues with the format of an input file, and fixed it with a long pipeline of `sed` and `awk`pieces... maybe [my question and the answers to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453057/use-sed-or-awk-to-fix-date-format) may help you

Comment: As an alternative, I frequently use something like this for exporting data from MySQL: `mysql [connectionParameters] -e"select ..." | sed 's/\t/,/g' > output.csv`

Comment: This is a longshot, but maybe `sep = '\\t'`? :/

Comment: @Barranka: My goal is to help a certain user use MySQL dumps from a MySQL instance that that user does not have a direct access. Moreover, the user uses Windows, so I wanted to avoid text processing tools. I'll try to hack something to read the contents character by character and maybe do a parser from scratch.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski: The thing is that '\\t' is not separator, it's '\t' that is meant to be part of the field. So, exactly the opposite meaning.