# awk command to convert date format in a file

Tags: shell, awk

Given below is the file content and the awk command used:

**Input file:in_t.txt**

```
1,ABC,SSS,20-OCT-16,4,1,0,5,0,0,0,0
2,DEF,AAA,20-JUL-16,4,1,0,5,0,0,0,0
```

**Expected outfile:**

```
SSS|2016-10-20,5
AAA|2016-07-20,5
```

I tried the below command:

```
awk -F , '{print $3"|"$(date -d 4)","$8}' in_t.txt
```

**Got the outfile as:**

```
SSS|20-OCT-16,5
AAA|20-JUL-16,5
```

Only thing I want to know is on how to format the date with the same awk command. Tried with

```
awk -F , '{print $3"|"$(date -d 4)","$8 +%Y-%m-%d}' in_t.txt
```

Getting syntax error. Can I please get some help on this?

Comment: Do it in `awk` itself. That is probably more efficient than calling `date` for every line.

Comment: But how do I do that? I want to format the date and the same is not working.

Comment: Use `split` for dividing the input date and then convert the month name to the number

Comment: Just with the **awk** its not possible?

Comment: `$(date -d 4)` is not calling the `date` command nor doing anything outside of the awk program. It is simply concatenating two empty strings with "4" and using the `$` to take the value of the 4th field, as you're seeing in the output.

Comment: Oh alright, so with a single **awk** command this is not possible?

Comment: There is nothing which can be done with a single command?

Comment: @jas well spotted but it's not QUITE concatenating 2 empty string. The `-` in `-d` is turning it into a numeric op with result `0`.

Comment: awk -F, '{print | "date -d "$4" \"+%Y-%m-%d\","$1","$8}' in_t.txt. Got this solution working. I want to understand more details on this. 

What does adding | inside print signify? Also $1 and $8, how to add it before date command?

Comment: [You've asked 40 questions on this forum so far](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4456527/programmer). Why are you now running around posting the same comment under multiple answers, none of which even provided the code in your comment, and under this 5-year-old question containing  a new question instead of simply asking your 41st question? This is even worse than the usual [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)! If you have a followup question to ask then simply post a question, reference your existing one if that's useful

Comment: sure will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your definition of a single command? A call to awk is a single shell command. This may be what you want:

```
$ awk -F'[,-]' '{ printf "%s|20%02d-%02d-%02d,%s\n", $3, $6, (match("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",$5)+2)/3, $4, $10 }' file
SSS|2016-10-20,5
AAA|2016-07-20,5
```

BTW it's important to remember that **awk is not shell**. You can't call shell tools (e.g. `date`) directly from awk any more than you could from C. When you wrote `$(date -d 4)` awk saw an unset variable named `date` (numeric value `0`) from which you extracted the value of an unset variable named `d` (also `0`) to get the numeric result `0` which you then concatenated with the number `4` to get `04` and then applied the `$` operator to to get the contents of field `$04` (=`$4`). The output has nothing to do with the shell command `date`.

Comment: I can't decide whether to +1 or -1 for that beautiful nasty little `match()` hack...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the match() thing is the common awk idiom for this....

Comment: This helped me to solve my problem, thanks @EdMorton

Comment: awk -F, '{print | "date -d "$4" \"+%Y-%m-%d\","$1","$8}' in_t.txt. Got this solution working. I want to understand more details on this. What does adding | inside print signify? Also $1 and $8, how to add it before date command?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262829/awk-command-to-convert-date-format-in-a-file/38271260?noredirect=1#comment120534155_38262829

Answer (score 5):

Better to do this in shell itself and use `date -d` to convert the `date` format:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -ra arr; do
   printf "%s|%s,%s\n" "${arr[2]}" $(date -d "${arr[3]}" '+%Y-%m-%d') "${arr[7]}"
done < file

SSS|2016-10-20,5
AAA|2016-07-20,5
```

Comment: awk -F, '{print | "date -d "$4" \"+%Y-%m-%d\","$1","$8}' in_t.txt. Got this solution working. I want to understand more details on this. What does adding | inside print signify? Also $1 and $8, how to add it before date command?

Comment: `|` is just a delimiter in output after `SSS`. Since I didn't provide an awk answer here to cannot explain that in this answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262829/awk-command-to-convert-date-format-in-a-file/38271260?noredirect=1#comment120534155_38262829

Answer (score 1):

From [Unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/81194-using-awk-convert-dd-mmm-yy-yyyymmdd.html)

Just tweaked it a little to suit your needs

```
awk -v var="20-OCT-16" '
BEGIN{
  split("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC", month, " ")
  for (i=1; i<=12; i++) mdigit[month[i]]=i
  m=toupper(substr(var,4,3))
  dat="20"substr(var,8,2)"-"sprintf("%02d",mdigit[m])"-"substr(var,1,2) 
  print dat
}'


2016-10-20
```

**Explanation:**

```
Prefix 20 {20}
Substring from 8th position to 2 positions {16}
Print - {-}
Check for the month literal (converting into uppercase) and assign numbers (mdigit) {10}
Print - {-}
Substring from 1st position to 2 positions {20}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you also.

```
awk -F , 'BEGIN {months = "  JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"}
    { num = index(months, substr($4,4,3)) / 3
    if (length(num) == 1) {num = "0" num}
    date = "20" substr($4,8,2) "-" num "-" substr($4,1,2)
    print $3"|" date "," $8}' in_t.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your call to `date`. You can indeed use it with `getline` to parse and output the date value:

```
awk -F',' '{
parsedate="date --date="$2" +%Y-%m-%d"
parsedate | getline mydate
close(parsedate)
print $3"|"mydate","$8
}'
```

Explanation:

- `-F','` sets the field separator (delimiter) to comma
- `parsedate="date --date="$2" +%Y-%m-%d"` leverages `date`'s [ability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) to convert the 2nd field to a given output format and assigns that command to the variable "parsedate"
- `parsedate | getline mydate` runs your custom "parsedate" command, and assigns the output to the `mydate` variable
- `close (parsedate)` prevents certain errors with multiline input/output (See [Running a system command in AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630820/10376320) for discussion of `getline` and `close()`)
- `print $3"|"mydate","$8` outputs the contents of the original line separated by pipe and comma with the new "mydate" value substituted for field 2.