# How to get a unique value of the same value in both columns in a Unix command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a huge csv file I want to know the same source IP address and destination IP address unique value and how to convert my log timing format

```
"Date", "User Information", "Source IP", "Destination IP", "HTTP Status Code", "HTTP Method", "URL", "Receive byte", "Send byte"
"[31/Jul/2018:21:11:55 +0900] ","ayw23","17.248.157.14","17.248.157.14","247","CONNECT","setup.iciwh.com:443","2938","600"
```

So compare the use of awk?

```
cat file.csv| awk '$6 == $7'
```

I like to get such output

```
2018/7/31 21:11   17.248.157.14  setup.iciwh.com:443
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparing the value in your case, you should use `-F` option of `awk` as in your case, field separator is `,` and not `space`

```
awk -F, '{ if( $6 == $7) print "equal" }' test.csv
```

or

```
awk -F,  ' $6 == $7 { print "equal" }' test.csv
```

Also, because the first line is header and you would not want to have a condition on this line, you can include condition `NR >1`

```
awk -F,  'NR >1 && $6 != $7 { print $6 $7 }' test.csv
```

For date conversion, kindly look at below link. There many suggestions are provided to achieve this

[awk command to convert date format in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262829/awk-command-to-convert-date-format-in-a-file)