# How do I pass the output of a command that contains quotes as an awk variable?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Looking to set a date variable withing awk but can't get the quoting or syntax right!

```
awk -v c=$i -v d="date +\"%D %r %Z\"" '{print d c }'
```

Comment: @Tony Huh? What a rude comment. Please delete it or consider changing to something more constructive.

Comment: Try `BEGIN` before the `{print d c }`, or otherwise you have to supply some input lines to get `awk` to execute the `print`.

Comment: Can you include actual and expected output?

Comment: A title that distinguishes this question from [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) and [Assigning system command's output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable) would be an improvement. The current title ("*awk variable quotes and escaping*") is so vague that without clicking through, one could expect it to be a duplicate of either or both.

Answer (score 5):

Consider instead:

```
awk -v d="$(date +'%D %r %Z')" 'BEGIN{print d}'
```

The changes here are:

1. Use `$()` to execute date and get the output back for the variable `d`.
2. Using single quotes for the `date` format so you don't have double quotes in double quotes
3. Using `BEGIN` to execute the `print` statement in awk. This isn't necessary if you are feeding a file or stdin to awk for it to read records.

Comment: Double quotes inside the double quotes would be fine now that you're adding a `$()`-based command substitution -- since that creates a whole new quoting context; `d="$(date +"%D %r %Z")"` would work just as well as the current answer does. As such, while its suggestion (of using single-quotes wherever possible) *is* best practice, I'm not sure that the first line of this answer is on-point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How right you are. My first instinct was to pull my hair out on behalf of OP and then fix it all up. But in fixing it all up I solved the hair pulling out scenario. I've removed my first sentence!

Comment: There's some chance OP wants to timestamp each line of output as it comes in, but it's not clear from the question

Comment: @thatotherguy I have to imagine that's the case here too, which is why I mentioned that the `BEGIN` is only to make this completely superfluous and utterly useless waste of resource sample code to work.