# Converting timestamp to EPOCH in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am converting timestamps to EPOCH seconds in `awk`, getting incorrect output for repeated timestamps

Input:

```
20180614 00:00:00
20180614 00:00:23
20180614 22:45:00
20180614 22:45:21
20180614 00:00:00
20180614 00:00:23
```

Expected Output :

```
1528930800
1528930823
1528930800
1529012721
1528930800
1528930823
```

I did

```
awk '{ ts="\""$0"\""; ("date +%s -d "ts)| getline epochsec; print epochsec}'
```

output after running above command:

```
1528930800
1528930823
1529012700
1529012721
1529012721
1529012721
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU xargs:

```
xargs -I {} date +%s -d {} < file
```

Output:

```
1528927200
1528927223
1529009100
1529009121
1528927200
1528927223
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit a shorter GNU awk version is using [`FIELDWIDTHS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fixed-width-data) which is available from `gawk-2.13` onwards:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 3 2 1 2 1 2"}{print mktime($1" "$2" "$3$4" "$6" "$8)}'
```

Since gawk-4.2 you can [skip intervening fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Skipping-intervening):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2 1:2 1:2 1:2"}{print mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6)}'
```

Or even shorter using [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9][0-9]"}{print mktime($1$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7)}
```

**note:** the usage of a single `awk`-`mktime` combination will be faster than anything which makes system calls to `date` as you do not constantly have to call a binary. With the `awk` mktime solution you call a single binary. Nonetheless, the `xargs` solution given by [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943491/8344060) is by far the most comfortable one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `system` function

```
$ awk '{system("date +%s -d \""$0"\"")}' ip.txt
1528914600
1528914623
1528996500
1528996521
1528914600
1528914623
```

Or use `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*/date +%s -d "&"/e' ip.txt
1528914600
1528914623
1528996500
1528996521
1528914600
1528914623
```

As per [AllAboutGetline article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170524214527/http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline), you'll need

```
$ awk '{ ts="date +%s -d \""$0"\""; while ((ts|getline ep)>0) print ep; close(ts) }' ip.txt 
1528914600
1528914623
1528996500
1528996521
1528914600
1528914623
```

However `getline` is not needed at all for this case and avoid using it unless you really need it and know how to use it

Comment: Thanks Sundeep for Suggestions and Answer... Its working

Comment: how can store output of system("date +%s -d \""$0"\"") to a variable in awk? I need to find the avg of time

Comment: seems like you need to use getline for that as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable ...

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk `mktime` function:

```
 awk '{gsub(":"," ",$2); print mktime(substr($1,1,4) " " substr($1,5,2) " " substr($1,7,2) " " $2)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Cyrus's answer, the following works on Mac OSX. Strangely, MAC has a different way of handling date-time format to epoch conversion.

```
xargs -I {} date -j -u -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" {} +%s < file
```